# Gradle: How to compile classes that use com.sun.xml.internal.bind.*?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2, classpath, gradle

I'm in the process of converting an existing project from ant to Gradle.

Unfortunately there is a Java class that uses com.sun.xml.internal.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl. For one thing I'm going to look into replacing that usage, but at this point I'm just curious why Gradle cannot find that class, which results in a compilation failure.

The message is

```
package com.sun.xml.internal.bind does not exist
```

Note that it compiles fine in eclipse as well as using the javac ant task. JAVA_HOME is set to 1.6.0_27.

So what is unique about Gradle that by default causes it to not find this class and how could someone workaround this issue?

See Java code snippet followed by build.gradle file:

```
final class Test{
    private static final javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterInterface DTC = com.sun.xml.internal.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl.theInstance;

    .....
    DTC.printDateTime(Calendar.getInstance());
}
```

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = "com.foo.bar.Test"
sourceCompatibility = 1.6
version = '5.4.0'

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Foo', 'Implementation-Version': version, 'Implementation-Vendor': 'Bar'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'commons-lang', name: 'commons-lang', version: '2.4'    
    compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '10.0.1'    
    compile group: 'org.hibernate.javax.persistence', name: 'hibernate-jpa-2.0-api', version: '1.0.1.Final'    
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '3.6.7.Final'
    compile group: 'jdom', name: 'jdom', version: '1.0'        
    compile group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version: '1.2.16'

    runtime group: 'antlr', name: 'antlr', version: '2.7.6'
    runtime group: 'backport-util-concurrent', name: 'backport-util-concurrent', version: '3.1'
    runtime group: 'c3p0', name: 'c3p0', version: '0.9.1.2'
    runtime group: 'cglib', name: 'cglib', version: '2.2'
    runtime group: 'commons-beanutils', name: 'commons-beanutils', version: '1.8.3'
    runtime group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec', version: '1.3'
    runtime group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.2.1'
    runtime group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '1.4'    
    runtime group: 'commons-logging', name: 'commons-logging', version: '1.1.1'    
    runtime group: 'dom4j', name: 'dom4j', version: '1.6.1'
    runtime group: 'javassist', name: 'javassist', version: '3.12.0.GA'    
    runtime group: 'javax.transaction', name: 'jta', version: '1.1'        
    runtime group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.6.2'
    runtime group: 'xerces', name: 'xerces', version: '2.4.0'        
    runtime group: 'xerces', name: 'xercesImpl', version: '2.10.0'
    runtime group: 'xml-apis', name: 'xml-apis', version: '2.0.2'                
}
```

EDIT

```
C:\>gradle -v

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 1.0-milestone-3
------------------------------------------------------------

Gradle build time: Monday, 25 April 2011 5:40:11 PM EST
Groovy: 1.7.10
Ant: Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 20 2010
Ivy: 2.2.0
JVM: 1.6.0_27 (Sun Microsystems Inc. 20.2-b06)
OS: Windows XP 5.1 x86
```

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13068146/how-to-overcome-package-com-sun-xml-internal-xxx-does-not-exist-when-compiling

Answer (score 3):

- Solution #1:

Copy (not move) rt.jar to a location different than `<JDK_install_dir>\jre\lib\rt.jar`
  (for example to `c:\rt.jar`) and run your compiler like below:

```
javac -cp c:\rt.jar your_file.java
```

- Solution #2:

Compile with compiler option `-XDignore.symbol.file=true`

Comment: Said link is broken. More information can be found here, for example: http://openjdk.java.net/projects/sctp/html/sctp6.html

Answer (score 1):

Gradle also uses the `javac` Ant task underneath. Compiling the class with a `build.gradle` that only contains `apply plugin: "java"` works fine for me with Gradle 1.0-milestone-3 on Mac OS 10.6. So my best guess is that you are running Gradle with a JRE rather than a JDK, or with 1.5 rather than 1.6.

Try to put the following into the build script and see if it works:

```
// only available in JDK 1.6
println javax.tools.ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler()
```

Comment: Yes it prints out com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool@1d4e49a. I don't have JDK 5 on my system so I don't think it is that. Any other idea? Thx.

Comment: Try with a build script that only contains `apply plugin: "java"`. Which OS? Which Gradle version (`gradle -v`)?

Comment: I added version info at the bottom of the post -- trying to reduce the build script now to a minimum.

Answer (score 1):

why not just use:

```
javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printDateTime(Calendar.getInstance());
```

Comment: That seems fine and compiles, but I'm still trying to figure out what the issue is though. Seems like it should work even though it is obviously better not to use those com.sun.* classes.

Comment: Is `com.sun.xml.internal.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl` found when used in the build script?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently which you can find more information about in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16803343/javax-cannot-be-imported-in-my-android-app).

I solved it by referencing this [library](https://github.com/openforis/android-ports/tree/master/android-jaxb) which you can see that `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterInterface` is included [here](https://github.com/openforis/android-ports/blob/master/android-jaxb/src/main/java/org/arbonaut/xml/bind/DatatypeConverterInterface.java).

I packaged the library and referenced it by my application.

Answer (score 0):

reason:
javac uses a special symbol table that does not include all Sun-proprietary classes. When javac is compiling code it doesn't link against rt.jar by default. Instead it uses special symbol file lib/ct.sym with class stubs.
solution:

```
compileJava {options.bootClasspath = "$System.env.JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/rt.jar"}
```