# How to overcome "package com.sun.xml.internal.xxx does not exist" when compiling with Gradle?

Tags: gradle

I want to compile java code that uses some Java's deprecated "sun" packages and Gradle compile task fails with this error

```
error: package com.sun.xml.internal.ws.developer does not exist
```

I am using Hotspot JDK and I can see this package there (so it actually exists - in rt.jar file)
I also tried to add rt.jar itself into Gradle dependencies:

```
compile files( 'C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/rt.jar')
```

but with no effect

here is my gradle -v output:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 1.2
------------------------------------------------------------

Gradle build time: Streda, 2012, september 12 10:46:02 UTC
Groovy: 1.8.6
Ant: Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.4 compiled on May 22 2012
Ivy: 2.2.0
JVM: 1.7.0_05 (Oracle Corporation 23.1-b03)
OS: Windows 7 6.1 amd64
```

I also tried to add jaxws-rt.jar to classpath - no effect neither

I would really appreciate any help

thanks

Comment: It may be that those packages are no longer part of JDK 7 on AMD64.

Comment: no, when I unzip rt.jar, I can it there

Comment: Then it should be in the CLASSPATH.

Comment: no, it is in classpath - compile files( 'C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/rt.jar')

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's Oracle's intent that these classes be inaccessible at compile-time.

See the response to [this javac bug report](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug;jsessionid=1711ee4eae3ff10565fc7a212018?bug_id=6778491).

For a likely solution, see [Using internal sun classes with javac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065401/using-internal-sun-classes-with-javac) .  The `javac -XDignore.symbol.file` switch should fix this - but I'm a gradle newb, and don't see how to feed this to [gradle's JavaCompile](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile:options).  My best guess is

```
  apply plugin: 'java' 
  compileJava.options.useAnt = true 
  compileJava.options.compilerArgs << "-XDignore.symbol.file"
```

Incidentally, ct.sym (referred to in the link) appears to be a jar-file that lists, as class stubs, all the accessible classes.

Comment: Gradle doesn't use a class loader for this, and it doesn't exclude anything. It just invokes the Java compiler API with all available information (e.g. compile class path). I believe it's the Java compiler (API) that disallows usage of certain internal JDK packages. Here is a reported case where explicitly adding rt.jar solved the problem: http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/package_sun_text_normalizer_does_not_exist

Comment: Peter: I tried it on a new project (to make sure I did not reuse my old mistakes) and it still does not work :(

Comment: also when I build my project in Idea, it works

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser - thanks for showing the way - see updated answer with specifics, and (hopefully) a partial better solution.  I cross-posted onto the forum thread in hope that it's useful.

Comment: @user1746915 - IDE's do all sort of tricks with the compiler.  If you're trying to come at this from a neutral perspective, to confirm that gradle isn't causing the problem, try compiling a tiny .java with the problem import from the command line.

Comment: Compiling from the command line isn't the same, because by default, Gradle uses the Java compiler API, which doesn't behave exactly the same as the Oracle JDK command-line compiler.

Comment: It works :-)
     apply plugin: 'java'
     compileJava.options.useAnt = true
     compileJava.options.compilerArgs << "-XDignore.symbol.file"

Thank you

Comment: useAnt has been removed in recent versions of Gradle. "`options.fork = true; options.forkOptions.executable = 'javac'`" worked for me. See: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/java-compiler-ignore-symbol-file/8774

Comment: I am struggling in same issue but I am using Ant build, my solution is to update the javac tag in the build.xml such that:
  <javac srcdir="src" destdir="${classes.dir}" classpathref="classpath" memoryinitialsize="512m" memorymaximumsize="1024m" fork="true">
   <compilerarg line="-encoding utf-8 -XDignore.symbol.file"/>
   <exclude name="test/**"/>
  </javac>