# Sun JPEGImageEncoder compilation in Gradle

Tags: java, ant, gradle

I need to compile a code which uses `com.sun.image.codec.jpeg` package and its friends. I know, I know, its our company legacy code and we need to compile it as is.
My problem is - Eclipse compile those files without problem, it just works.
IDEA do the same - compile and works.
The problem is Gradle - it gives me errors like

```
error: package com.sun.image.codec.jpeg does not exist
```

I know - add `-XDignore.symbol.file` to compilator.

I did

```
compileJava.options.compilerArgs.add '-XDignore.symbol.file'
```

in my build.grade, I turned verbose mode and I see parameter gets passed correctly

```
20:28:16.148 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler] Compiler arguments: -d C:\workspace\blabla -g -XDignore.symbol.file -classpath C:\workspace\blabla_lots_of_jars.jar  C:\workspace\tons_of_java_files.java
20:28:16.153 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.jdk6.Jdk6JavaCompiler] Compiling with JDK Java compiler API.
```

But compilation fails. On [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13068146/how-to-overcome-package-com-sun-xml-internal-xxx-does-not-exist-when-compiling) I found that I should add to gradle file a line

```
compileJava.options.useAnt = true
```

which makes, you guessed, that everything compiles. The debug log is a bit different, but shows that also params are passed correctly

```
21:50:34.101 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] [ant:javac] Compilation arguments:
'-d'
'C:\workspace\blabla'
'-classpath'
'tons_of_jars'
'-target'
'1.7'
'-g'
'-XDignore.symbol.file'
'-source'
'1.7'
```

But `useAnt` will be removed and its seems like a dirty hack.

I use newest Gradle (1.8) and jdk1.7.0_25 on Win8 - but I doubt it matters

How can I make Gradle properly compile my sources and respect my compilation parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell, the JDK compiler API (which is what the `JavaCompile` task uses) silently ignores the `-XDignore.symbol.file` flag (I've also seen this for some other options). For now, the only solution that I'm aware of is to fall back to the Ant based compiler, even though it's deprecated.

EDIT: Another option is to force the `JavaCompile` task to use the `javac` command line compiler:

```
compileJava {
    options.fork = true
    options.forkOptions.executable = "javac" // assumes that javac is on PATH
    options.compilerArgs << "-XDignore.symbol.file"
}
```

Comment: It works, but not on Windows :) I reported this in more appropriate thread [there](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/running_a_java_compilation_in_forked_mode_on_windows_8_hangs?rfm=1)