# Eclipse build war success, but Maven command canot

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I code Java 7 on Java 8 JDK
When I run

```
mvn clean install
```

it show error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project foo: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /E:/bar/XmlUtils.java:[9,44] package com.sun.xml.internal.bind.marshaller does not exist
[ERROR] /E:/bar/XmlUtils.java:[11,34] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class CharacterEscapeHandler
[ERROR] /E:/.../FooServiceImpl.java:[106,44] package com.sun.xml.internal.bind.marshall
```

This is line of code make error

```
CharacterEscapeHandler.class.getName()
```

Maven can't find
    import com.sun.xml.internal.bind.marshaller.CharacterEscapeHandler;

Maven can't find `CharacterEscapeHandle`. How to fix it?

but when I build, package, run by Eclipse Neon, no problem. How to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13068146/how-to-overcome-package-com-sun-xml-internal-xxx-does-not-exist-when-compiling..???

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is temporary solution

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>sun.jdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>rt.jar</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <compilerArgument>-XDignore.symbol.file</compilerArgument>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Maven builds success.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you should not use any code from  package com.sun.xml.internal. And this fails intentionally. Here are more details: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do;jsessionid=1711ee4eae3ff10565fc7a212018?bug_id=6778491

Comment: As they're internal packages, they have absolutely no guarantees. They can be gone the next update.