# Compilation Error error: package com.sun.xml.internal.bind.marshaller does not exist

Tags: java, maven

I am using deprecated Java Sun packages that can only be found in rt.Jar, when I compile in jdk 1.8 it works fine, but I am now using jdk 11 and when I compile it throws the following

> Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.0:compile (default-compile) on project agency: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
>   com/simpay/uba/agency/mapper/XmlBuilder.java:[8,43] error: package com.sun.xml.internal.bind.marshaller does not exist
>   com/simpay/uba/agency/mapper/XmlCharacterHandler.java:[12,43] error: package com.sun.xml.internal.bind.marshaller does not exist
>   com/simpay/uba/agency/mapper/XmlCharacterHandler.java:[19,44] error: cannot find symbol
>   symbol: class CharacterEscapeHandler

Basically I'm trying to unescape a CDATA payload before sending so I need the following libraries above. 
Below is my maven plugin I added which works fine on jdk 1.8

```
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source> 
                    <target>11</target> 
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-XDignore.symbol.file</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source> 
                    <target>11</target> 
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-XDignore.symbol.file</arg>  
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
      </plugins>
```

I even tried this link solution from this [link](https://gist.github.com/matrixcloud/d3e97325621748401d82c4134c11226e) but it seems like that `<bootclasspath/>` has been deprecated also. I tried 3.0, 3.3, 3.8.1, 3.7, and 3.6 of the maven compiler plugins. No effect also. I have looked at the following links [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13068146/how-to-overcome-package-com-sun-xml-internal-xxx-does-not-exist-when-compiling) [link2](https://www.pixelstech.net/article/1428721058-Add-compiler-argument-to-build-Maven-project) none of which solves my problem on jdk 11.

Comment: The JVM has been slimmed. You probably need to repackage your code with what is available now

Comment: https://www.jesperdj.com/2018/09/30/jaxb-on-java-9-10-11-and-beyond/